# Storage Patterns: Transforming multiple mappings -> structs with mapping

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Currently I have quiet a few mappings which I believe overall could be reduced to a struct with internal mappings and one overall mapping, however, I'm not sure how to do this myself and are therefore looking for guidance.

```
mapping(address => uint256)    public proposedOfferings;
mapping(address => uint256)    public receivedOfferings;
mapping(address => uint256)    public acceptedOfferings;
mapping(address => uint256)    public rejectedOfferings;
```

How can I re-structure above to below, keeping in mind each mapping consist of two separate `uint256` variables (e.g. `uint256 amount` and `uint256 percentageBonus`).

```
struct offerings {
mapping(address=> uint256) proposed;
mapping(address=> uint256) received;
mapping(address=> uint256) accepted;
mapping(address=> uint256) rejected;
}

mapping(address => offerings) offeringData;
```

also, some information on the related design paradigm would be highly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Your code still does not reflect that the addresses are mapped to an array of size 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct param {
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 percentageBonus;
}

struct offerings {
    param proposed;
    param received;
    param accepted;
    param rejected;
}

mapping(address => offerings) public offeringData;
```

Like this, you will be mapping each address to a structure with four fields (proposed, received... etc) each of these fields have two fields (amount and percentageBonus)

you can use it like this, assume the user address is A:

`offeringData[A].proposed.amount` will give you the amount proposed by the user with address A.

`offeringData[A].proposed.percentageBonus` give you the percentage bonus. Same for the other variables.

You can set these doing, for instance,: `offeringData[A].proposed.amount = value`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Each of the mappings however contain two uint256 variables, so I can't use your approach as far as my knowledge goes. I'll edit my answer for more clarity.

Comment: This is not reflected in your question, you have an address mapping to a number. You mean these are uint256 arrays?

Comment: I updated the answer to make every variable in the struct an array of two positions, you will use, for instance, `offerings.proposed[0]` to access the first element of proposed.

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other, maybe I'm not completely clear in my definitions. I apologise if that's the case. 
Each mapping consist of two separate uint256 variables  (e.g. uint256 amount and uint256 percentageBonus),  and not an array of size 2.

Comment: are the names of the 2 variables the same for each mapping?

Comment: yes same name for each variable for each mapping

Comment: Done, let me know if this solves your problem. The solution is to have a structure inside a structure.

Comment: Yep this was the solution, thanks for the help jaime.

Answer (score 1):

Your offering should be a struct:

```
struct offering {
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 percentageBonus;
}
```

After this, you can do:

```
mapping(address => offering) public proposedOfferings;
mapping(address => offering) public receivedOfferings;
mapping(address => offering) public acceptedOfferings;
mapping(address => offering) public rejectedOfferings;
```

Or even:

```
struct offerings {  /* please note that is plural */
    mapping(address => offering) proposed;
    mapping(address => offering) received;
    mapping(address => offering) accepted;
    mapping(address => offering) rejected;
}

mapping(address => offerings) offeringData;
```

It will help to understand more about the business logic behind this, because it seems your offerings can be on different states, and an alternative approach could be to use an **enum** to describe such states:

```
enum offeringState { Received, Proposed, Accepted, Rejected }

struct offering {
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 percentageBonus;
    offeringState state;
}
```

But I'm really taking a wild guess now.

Comment: This could be an alternative approach as well, thanks for insight!